# MVC2 Login verification with windows Basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, windows-authentication

I am using [windows basic authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb), if user is verified home controller is displayed.  Only user those who belong to "Admin" group are allowed to access this site. so far all works well. I am using below code. I want to log message in database if user tries to login and does not belong to "Admin" group. Any suggestion how to achieve that?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]                
public ActionResult Home()
{
..............
return View();
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options, write a custom authorize attribute which logs on failure or create an HTTPModule which detects 401's and logs there. Personally i prefer the custom authorize attribute approach